# Number of sequences $a_1, \dots,a_{12}$ with conditions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

> Find the number of sequences $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10},a_{11},a_{12}$ which fulfill the following conditions: $$
> a_k^2=a_k,\quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^{12} a_i=7,\quad \sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i\geq \frac{k}{2}\quad 
> $$
>   for every $1\leq k\leq 12$.

I'm struggling to find a *catalan-numbers-approach* to this problem. (if there exists)

Comment: Each a is 0 or 1.  There are 5 zeros and 7 ones.  a1 = 1.

Comment: $C_{5}\binom{7}{2}$?

Comment: You have yet to consider the rest of the third condition.